# problem with setState and too many re-renders

Tags: reactjs

I am using functional components in react.

I have a Game component that is the display parent. It has a parent called Main which houses all the functions and variables for Game. I am getting the too many re-renders bug when I try to set the state of a particular variable. It is triggered by the startGame() method which calls an API and then calls another function with the data  to set 4-6 variables. I can use the setState on 6 of the variables without issue but any time I try to 'setPlayers', it creates a too many re-renders bug.

I am clueless as to why this one variable is special. I temporarily solved the problem by switching Players to a regular variable at which point I can assign its value no problem but I would like to understand what's going on.

Main.jsx

```
    let [isBet, setIsBet] = useState(false);
    let [betOptions, setBetOptions] = useState();
    let [hasStarted, setHasStarted] = useState(false);
    let [id, setId] = useState(0);
    const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]) ////The variable that causes the issue
        // let players = []; //doesn't cause issue
    const [cards, setCards] = useState([])
    const [hand, setHand] = useState([])
    const [betLog, setBetLog] = useState([])
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("")

    const setVariables= data => {
        setHasStarted(true)
        setId(data.gameId)
        setPlayers(data.users) ///// !!!!! causes too many re-renders bug
        // players = data.users // if I use this line instead of the above, the function works
        // setPlayers([...data.users])
        setHand(data.hand)
        console.log("BET OPTIONS", data.betOptions)
        if (data.betOptions.name === username){
            setBet(data.betOptions)
        } 
    }

    const setBet = betOptions => {
        setBetOptions(betOptions)
        console.log("Your Bet Options are", betOptions)
        console.log(betOptions.betAmount)
        setIsBet(true)
    }

    const startGame = async (state) => {
        let body = { username, 
            displayName : state.displayName,
            numberOfPlayers : state.numberOfPlayers,
            fillWithComputerPlayers: state.fillWithComputerPlayers,
            isCustom: state.isCustom,
            bigBlind: state.bigBlind
         }
        try {
            const data = await Service.startGame(body);
            console.log("response body", data.data)
            setVariables(data.data);
        } catch (err){
            console.error(err)
            setErrorMessage(err.message)
            setShowModal(true)
            setTimeout(function(){
                setShowModal(false)
            }, (2500))
        }
    }
```

All the variables are being used by the child component, Game. I am not using any UseEffect on 'players' but it is the only one of the relevant variables on which I am using a .map() (note- I am also mapping 'cards' and setting it in exactly the same way but in a different function). That is the only use of the 'players' variable.

Game.jsx

```
    let id = props.id;
    // let [players] = useState(props.players)
    let players = props.players
    let hand = props.hand;
    let betOptions = props.betOptions;
    let cards = props.cards
    const [money, setMoney] = useState(0)
    const username = props.username;

return ( 
        <div id="background">

         /// Lots of other components not relevant to the question
                {props.hasStarted ? 
                    <div> 
                        {players.map((v, i) => {    /////// !! only use of players
                            if (v.username !== username){
                                return (
                                    <PlayerInfo name={v.username} money={v.money} key={i} class="info" />

                                )
                            } else {
                                setMoney(v.money)
                            }                           
                        })}
                        {cards.length > 0 && cards.map((v, i) => {
                            return (
                                <img className="cards" key={i} src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/pics/PNG/' + v.image} alt={v.image} />
                            )
                        })}
                         <div id="my">
                            <MyInfo name={username} money={money} hand={hand} class="info" /> 
                        </div>      
                    </div>                   
                :
                    <SettingsForm startGame={props.startGame} username={username} />
                }
            
            </div>

            
            <Log betLog={props.betLog} />

        </div>
```

PlayerInfo.jsx

```
import "./Info.css"

const PlayerInfo = props => {

    return ( 
        <div className="info">
           <h4>{props.name}</h4> {props.money}$
            <div>          
               <img className="cards" src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/pics/PNG/red_back.png'} alt="card" />
               <img className="cards" src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/pics/PNG/red_back.png'} alt="card" />
            </div>                    
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default PlayerInfo;
```

Comment: Could you please provide more context? Do you have any `useEffect` or children components that use `players`?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just turn as many of them as makes sense into 1 or more objects?
Unlike `setState` for 5 different pieces of state, which would cause 5 separate re-renders,
setting the state as 1 object containing all those 5 pieces would cause only 1 re-render.

Comment: Not a bad idea but I tried it out and same problem. I think I'll keep it condensed anyways.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry for misleading.
The "re-render" error in React essentially means that you have created an infinite loop, and since React was able to catch it, it simply threw an exception instead of freezing the entire browser.
Another common error for this is "Maximum update depth exceeded".
This usually happens when you try to use or depend on a piece of state that gets re-rendered as a result of it's use.